# Bivariate Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I'm midway through my first year tutoring a high school student in an introductory probability theory course, and I've come across a problem of hers that I find quite puzzling. The essense of the problem is that someone makes a mistake with p=0.04, and we're to let X represent the number of days until the first mistake is made and Y (worded exaxtly like this) is be the number of days *after the first mistake is made* until the second mistake is made.

The question lies in that we're to identify the joint and marginal pmfs of X and Y.
My understanding is that these are both geometric random variables with success parameter p=0.04, where a "success" in this case would be making a mistake. I'm having trouble finding out how to identify Y then, as it appears like the question wants you to identify Y as being conditional on X somehow, but I feel like the memoryless property of the geometric distribution also comes into play here. If anyone doesn't mind walking me through how they would interpret these random variables and deducing joint and independent pmfs for me, or giving me a direction to get started in, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like $p=0.04$ is the probability to make the first mistake *on a given day*.  What stops us to model the 2nd mistake just like the first mistake? You say "it appears like the question wants you to identify Y as being conditional on X somehow". My question is *how* ? Who knows? You should probably provide more details.

Comment: My interpretation, based on what you've said, would be that $X, Y$ should be independent geometric random variables with $p = 0.04$. But, I'd be curious to see the exact text of the problem to see if I'm misinterpreting anything.